# counting digits while reading from a file

Tags: java, file, io, try-catch

let's say I have a file of mostly numbers, and some letter

```
1
4
5
d o
2
8 22
6
f
```

so I want to count the how many numbers and letters, and I can only use nextInt() method. Here's the code I'm using, but for some reason I get an endless loop, after doing some debugging (printing input) it will stop at number 5. why am I doing wrong here?

```
public static void mixedF() {
        int numbers = 0; 
        int words = 0;
        int num;      
        try {
            Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("myFile.txt"));
            while(in.hasNext()) {
                try {
                    num = in.nextInt();
                    System.out.println(num);
                    numbers++; 
                }
                catch (InputMismatchException e) { words++; }              

                }            

            System.out.println("numbrers: "+numbers);
            System.out.println("words: "+words);
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException ex) { ex.getMessage(); }        
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add `in.next();` to `catch`, otherwise the `scanner` won't move forward.

Comment: yeah, I just realize I got an endless loop in catch statement

Answer (score 0):

Problem: You are reading integers alone using nextInt() function.

When Scanner comes across a character it goes to the catch block. Try advancing the Scanner in catch block or the character 'd' will be read over and over again